# How can I find datasource from child EJB project?

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, websphere-8

This same thing works great in Liberty, but I have to make this work
using WebSphere 8.0...

I have an application with an EAR > WAR > EJB project structure.  The
idea is to start a batch process using a RESTful trigger though the
WAR, which uses the logic in the EJB to perform the taasks.  I have a
persistence helper in the EJB project that gets injected with the
EntityManager, and all is happy.

JPA is just too slow for the data and volume I need to inject, so
we've decided to use JDBC batch for importing the data in this
process, so I need a DataSource.  It's defined in the server console
(the persistence.xml is using it for JPA), I defined it in the web.xml
and ibm-web-bnd.xml, but I still can't seem to find it.  Moreover, if
I have a class in the WAR spit out the JNDI tree, I can see it under
java:comp/env/jdbc/MyDB, but from a class in the EJB, it's a different
tree.

web.xml:

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/MyDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
    <mapped-name>jdbc/MyDB</mapped-name>
</resource-ref>
```

ibm-web-bnd.xml:

```
<resource-ref name="jdbc/MyDB" binding-name="jdbc/MyDB" />
```

MyPersistence.java:

```
@Resource(name="jdbc/MyDB")
private DataSource datasource;
```

Do I need something additional to pass the datasource down to the EJB level?  That seems odd since the EntityManager is using it successfully.

As always, any help is appreciated!

**Post-Answer Edit:**

This is the entry I needed to add to the ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml, per Gas's answer:

```
<session name="MyPersistence" simple-binding-name="com.travelers.bi.errordb.persistence.MyPersistence">
    <resource-ref name="jdbc/MyDB" binding-name="jdbc/MyDB" />
</session>
```

Comment: what data source are you trying to use?  Not sure why you have shown bindings for `jdbc/MyDB` but then show resource injection for `jdbc/ErrorDB`

Comment: @aguibert - because typo

Comment: I'm not sure, if I understand your issue correctly (assuming you have some NameNotFound JNDI error). Add the `@Resource` annotation for Datasource in to your EJB class (same way as you added it to the MyPersistence class), and then create ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml file with similar resource reference binding as your ibm-web-bnd.xml file.

Comment: @Gas The ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml was the missing piece.  I've never had to do this with other JNDI objects, so I'm not sure what the difference is here.  If you post as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `@Resource` annotation for Datasource in to your EJB class (same way as you added it to the `MyPersistence` class), and then create `ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml` file with similar resource reference binding as your `ibm-web-bnd.xml` file.

Regarding the EJB binding file - the difference is that `ibm-web-bnd.xml` file is for resources used in your web module, like servlets etc. From Java EE 7, you can embed EJBs in the web module, but they still use their own annotations/deployment descriptors for references, thats why you have separate binding file for EJBs.